# How to use grep to find data conveniently and quickly

Tags: cygwin, grep

I am asking for general opinions on how to find files quickly.

One typical scenario is that I often need to grep some names from a PeopleNameFile.txt from Dir1. When I'm in a different directory, I am forced to grep the file with a long directory path. It would be nice to just do GREP "Warren Buffett" PeopleNameFile.txt.

BTW, I'm using Cygwin but I welcome any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily write a simple bash function in your ~/.bashrc:

```
function grnm() {
     grep "$@" /path/to/peoplenamefile.txt
}
```

Then later on, at command line you can type:

```
$ grnm "Warren Buffet"
```

the nice thing is that you can actually include other grep parameters if you like as in:

```
$ grnm -i "warren buffet"
```

(The `$` characters represent your shell prompt, not part of the command you type.)

When you edit the .bashrc file FOR THE FIRST TIME you may have to source it in your existing open cygwin windows:

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

But if you open a new window you should not have to do that.

Good luck, have fun

Answer (score 1):

You can create script my_grep.sh and add it somewhere to you path, with content like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep $1 path/to/Dir1/PeopleNameFile.txt
```

than you just type

```
my_grep.sh "Warren Buffett"
```

also you can use alias and bash's function,
but this require to edit "~/.bashrc".

Answer (score 0):

Simplest option would be to setup an alias which would grep for that file using the absolute path. Not sure whether cygwin allows aliases though.

Comment: Sure. cygwin includes bash. bash supports aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most common way to do these kind of things is to use environment variables

e.g.

```
PNF='/very/long/path/PeopleNameFile.txt'
grep "Warren Buffett" $PNF
```